# App Store views in Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, app-store, itunesconnect-analytics

Is it possible to connect iTunesConnect App Analytics and Google Analytics and see App Analytics data such as **Product Page Views**, **Impressions in Google Analytics Account**?

Comment: I know there are third-party solutions that can import and show data form both of them, but i need this data been shown in Google Analytics Account.

Comment: You might want to look into "Importing Data" to Google Analytics, there seems no be no end-to-end solution to just connect the two services. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191417?hl=en

For getting the data out of iTunes Connect have a look at Spaceship https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/3682